# could not enter folder /media/myuser/partitionname

Tags: hard-drive, permissions, kubuntu, media

My laptop has two hard drives: an SSD and an HDD. I put the root partition on the SSD and divided the HDD to two partitions, one for /home and the other contains my personal data.

After installing Kubuntu, I can't access it. In the Dolphin file manager, I get the error:

> Could not enter folder /media/haider/MyFiles

Is this a permissions issue or something else?

lsblk screenshot:
[image: lsblk screenshot]

media folder content:
[image: media folder content]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The folder `/media/haider` has the permissions `700` and is owned by `root`. This prevents anyone except `root` from doing anything to that directory.

Assuming your user name and group name is both `haider` you can change the ownership of the directory so you can access it:

```
sudo chown -R haider:haider /media/haider
```

This will set the user and group for `/media/haider` to `haider` and allow you to access the directory. This also applies to all files and subdirectories inside `/media/haider`

You could then set permissions to `750` to allow others in the `haider` group to `read` and `execute` on the directory, but not allow `write` access.

```
chmod 750 /media/haider
```

Other users in the `haider` group still might not be able to see or access any files if the permissions on the files and directories are still `700` inside `/media/haider`. It is fine to set the other directories to `750` but it is good practice to set files to `640` to avoid any possible security issues (of course, this is less of an issue for purely media files, but still good practice, nonetheless).

To set directories inside `/media/haider/` to `750`:

```
find /media/haider/. -type d -exec chmod 750 {} \;
```

To set files inside `/media/haider/` to `640`:

```
find /media/haider/. -type f -exec chmod 640 {} \;
```

I would recommend against setting `777` permissions on that folder for the purposes of allowing others access. Instead, utilize groups and set permissions on the folder to follow the [principle of least priviledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege).

Comment: thanks for your answer after trying your solution the ownership and permissions changed successfully but when i open the drive it's empty!!

Comment: `/media/haider` may need to be owned by `root` then. Try changing the ownership and group back:
`sudo chown root:root /media/haider` You might also need to do this with /media/haider/MyFiles: `sudo chown root:root /media/haider/MyFiles` If that works I will edit my answer accordingly.